# std::unique_ptr with lambda custom deleter doesnt compile

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, smart-pointers, core-foundation

Can't find whats the problem in following code

```
std::unique_ptr<CFStringRef, std::function<void(CFStringRef)>>
cfstr(CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, str, kCFStringEncodingUTF8),
                                 [](CFStringRef obj){
                                     CFRelease(obj);
                                 });
```

CFStringCreateWithCString should return correct type as per [CFStringCreateWithCString documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1542942-cfstringcreatewithcstring?language=objc)

Error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG -MMD -MT dependencies -MF -c DynamicStore.cpp -o DynamicStore.o

DynamicStore.cpp:29:5: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::unique_ptr<CFStringRef, std::function<void (CFStringRef)> >'
    cfstr((CFStringRef)CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, str, kCFStringEncodingUTF8),

main.cpp:73:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::for_each<std::__1::__wrap_iter<const std::__1::sub_match<const char *> *>, (lambda at main.cpp:73:45)>' requested here
        std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::cmatch &s){
             ^
main.cpp:73:45: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::__1::sub_match<const char *>' to 'const std::cmatch' (aka 'const match_results<const char *>') for 1st argument
        std::for_each(cm.begin(), cm.end(), [](const std::cmatch &s){
                                            ^
main.cpp:73:45: note: conversion candidate of type 'void (*)(const std::cmatch &)'
```

Comment: Could you side step this issue and provide a specialization of `default_delete` for your type?

Comment: Also seems like unless your templated type is a pointer, you need to define a deleter containing a `pointer` typedef, where the typedef is to the type to be passed to the deleter. Otherwise it uses `T*` as the argument to the deleter, which is wrong in this case. This would imply a lambda is not suitable to define a deleter in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building up on @NulledPointer quote:

```
struct CFStringRefDeleter {
    using pointer = CFStringRef;
    void operator()(CFStringRef ref) {
         CFRelease(ref);
    }
};
using CFStr_t = std::unique_ptr<CFStringRef, CFStringRefDeleter>;
CFStr_t cfstr(CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, str, kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
CFStringRef obj = cfstr.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that is enough but... if I'm not wrong the destructor use a pointer to the type, not an object of the type

I mean... you should define the type as

```
std::unique_ptr<CFStringRef, std::function<void(CFStringRef * )>>
                                                            ^    
                            note the pointer ---------------|
```

and the lambda should receive (and use) a pointer

```
[](CFStringRef * pObj){ CFRelease(*pObj) /* ? */ };
```

Comment: CFStringRef == CFString *. Deleter in case of std::unique_ptr calls `Deleter(T)` so Im not sure if you are right

Comment: This is other way around then. First template parameter of unique_ptr should be a type and not a pointer to type. So `std::unique_ptr<CFString, std::function<void(CFStringRef)>`

Comment: @AndreyTurkin CFString is opaque so should not be used

Comment: Also, its not always pointer to the type only if `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` exists

Comment: Oh, that possibility is cool to have. But `td::unique_ptr<CFStringRef, std::function<void(CFStringRef * )>>` still won't work - it would expect a pointer to `CFStringRef` in its constructor, not CFStringRef itself. You could write a custom deleter class which has `pointer` subtype typedefed to CFStringRef... which would also make second constructor argument not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "why" part to max's answer:

As per [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) doc

> -Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an
>   argument of type `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer`

Where `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer` is explained `member types`

> `unique_ptr<T, Deleter>::pointer` =   `std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type
>   exists, otherwise `T*`. Must satisfy NullablePointer